# Top Navigation Menu is hidden behind the silverlight webpart Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, web-part, css, navigation, silverlight

The top navigation drop down menu hides behind the Silverlight webpart. I've tried different CSS codes using script editor within the webpart but it still isn't working. I've tried changing the z-index and nothing.

This is in SharePoint 2013, and I've seen people post about this same issue for Sharepoint 2010, has anyone been able to find a solution?